# Connection refused while connecting to upstream from nginx to gunicorn_django

Tags: nginx, django, gateway, gunicorn

I'm trying to get my server back online after an upgrade, and I can no longer seem to get Nginx to direct calls to Gunicorn - every request I send to the site gets back a `502 Bad Gateway`. I have `gunicorn_django` running on port 8001 (as I can see from `ps aux | grep gunicorn` - the commands for the two workers have the argument `-b 0.0.0.0:8001`. My Nginx configuration has the following at the top of my only config in `sites-enabled`:

```
upstream django_test {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}
```

...so it should be directing requests to there. Nothing has changed about this config file since the upgrade.

When I visit `mysite.com/robots.txt` in my browser, it returns the `robots.txt` that I've defined in my `sites-enabled` config, so that file is definitely getting loaded. Furthermore when I run `curl 127.0.0.1` from the server I still get the `502 bad gateway`.

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the configuration of the virtualhost in /etc/nginx/sites-available and the corresponding symlink in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

Also check out the configuration of /bin/gunicorn-start and make sure the parameters match your setup.

There is more comprehensive information about configuring django with nginx and gunicorn following [this link](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/).